# symfony2 unable to find twig template

Tags: symfony

I am 2 hours new into Symfony2 so excuse my noob question. I am receiving an error stating:

```
Unable to find template "Akademiah:MemberBundle:Default:index.html.twig".
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
3 linked Exceptions: Twig_Error_Loader » InvalidArgumentException » InvalidArgumentException »
```

Not sure why this is showing as I am following a tutorial and things are expected to work at this stage?

I have the following in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Akademiah\MemberBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
            return $this->render('MemberBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('name'=>$name));    
    }
}
```

and I created the bundle using the PHP **app/console** command. Help is appreciated.

Comment: The template has to be located in `MemberBundle/Resources/view/Default/index.html.twig`.

Comment: it is mate and that is the default due to console generation of the bundle anyway. this is copied as shown src/Akademiah/MemberBundle/Resources/views/Default

Comment: Try `return $this->render('AkademiahMemberBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('name'=>$name)); `

Comment: getting different error now ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable:

Comment: What does your url look like?

Comment: this is it: http://domain.com/web/app_dev.php/hello/Fabien

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44011/discussion-between-markus-kottlander-and-spacemonkey)

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if a file called `index.html.twig` exists in your `resources/twig/default/` folder.  If it does not, create it.